# Is the Language below decidable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability, decision-problem

We define a language $L$:

$\qquad L=\{\langle M,w,k \rangle \mid M(w) \text{ reaches configuration } \alpha q \beta \text{ with } |\alpha \beta| \geq k \}$

with $M$ Turing machines with state set $Q$ and tape alphabet $\Gamma$, $\alpha$ and $\beta \in \Gamma^*$ , and $q \in {Q}$.

A configuration like this : 10q11 or  Bq11  are in standardform ,however those configurations  BB10q11 or B10q11BB are not ,  in other words if $\alpha $ starts with many blanks  then all the blanls will be one blank , same thing with $\beta$ when it ends with many blanks .

A configuration can be  like this  : 
[image: configuration example]

I am not sure if the language is decidable , but if i am able to find a machine which  decides L then it  must be decidable 
may main thoughts  about the contruction of the machine like below:

Let D the machine that decided L

1-after each step check if the configuration $\alpha q\beta$, with $\mid \alpha\beta \mid \geq k$, if yes then accept  else go further.

2-if until the i-step no configuration is found that  satisfied the condition and D  visted the  same  configuration twice ,which means it will go in a loop and then the condition won t be statisfied, then  we will reject
The problem here  which  i am not really sure about ,for how long do we need to wait until the loop is discovered ?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Is $q$ arbitrary in the definition of $L$?

Comment: There are many similar questions on the site: deciding whether $M$ ever moves the head to the right, ever writes a $0$, and so on and so on. All proofs are similar: deciding whether a TM does X is (usually) equivalent to deciding whether it holds, by similar and simple reductions.

Comment: I think the answer to this question depends on where $\alpha,q,\beta$ are quantified. Is there an implicit quantification inside your set definition, or are these variables fixed outside of it? Anyway, you should make the problem statement to be non ambiguous. If I had to guess, I'd guess that there is an implicit $\exists \alpha,q,\beta$ inside. In such case, I'd try to check how many such configurations exist -- if it is a finite or cofinite set, this might be useful.

Comment: the length of $\alpha$ and  $\beta$ depends on how does the  machine works , they are actually the  symbol of the  tape , on which  the machine writes .let $q_0$ be the start state and  w =1001 as input , and let s  say when the machine start  and it reads 1 , it writes 0 and go one step in the right and goes to state $q_i$ then it  will be like that : $q_0$1001$ \rightarrow$ 0$q_i$001

Comment: so for the configuration , we have $q_01001$ and $0q_i001$ , so for  $q_01001$=$ \alpha q_0 \beta$ with $\alpha$=B(blank) and $\beta =1001$, for  $0q_i001$ is $\alpha =0 $ and $\beta = 001$

Comment: head postion  is always the  first symbol in $\beta$